# Can 'chartbuster' be used for anything other than music?

Tags: word-usage

There is a chart for anything. The chart that lists top 5, 10 or 20 *anything.* *Busting* is probably used to show the impact of that *something* on the chart. The *thing* which is on the TOP of the list is certainly *chartbuster.*

In that sense, anything that tops the list can be called *chartbuster.* [I'm aware of the word *bestseller* which is used for the books].

But dictionaries say that its use is restricted to the list of *soundtracks.* Thinking in literary sense, *chartbuster* could be anything that tops the list.

Can we use *chartbuster* for anything other than music/soundtracks? Say games?

> We have developed some chartbuster games on Google Play and iTunes.

Comment: Books are usually called [_bestsellers_](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/u/new-york-times-bestsellers-books/379003574/), not _chartbusters_. Just because you _can_ put any data on a chart doesn't mean everyone will start referring to your chart as _the charts_ (as has happened with [pop music](http://www.billboard.com/charts)).

Comment: @J.R. I'm very much aware of *bestsellers*. Here, I'm talking about the chart of top rated **mobile games** on Google Play or iTunes. There they are quite clear about the ranking. May I use *chartbuster games*?

Comment: Read my comment more carefully. **Where are games "charted"?** (If that's not a standard use, I would avoid _chartbuster games_. Yes, you _can_ say it; yes, you _may_ say it, but that doesn't mean you _should_ say it.) I mentioned bestseller books because of your first two sentences. For books, they are called the _bestseller lists_, not the _bestseller charts_.

Comment: @J.R. OMG! Where did I mention books? What first two sentences? Books is out of context, completely. I said *anything* that tops the chart --games, articles, news, gadgets or anything...

Comment: _"There is a chart for **anything**."_ That wouldn't include books? _"The chart that lists top 5, 10 or 20 anything."_ That's not what a bestseller list does? _"Can we use_ chartbuster _for **anything** other than music/soundtracks? Say games?"_ Games would be one example. Books would be another. I don't see how "books" is out of context with "or anything..."

Comment: @J.R. Okay, *Bestseller* is quite a known noun for the books that I did not think to mention there first. True! Anything includes books but I wasn't concerned about it. Let me edit to clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Chartbuster* and *chartbusting* arose in the 1950s as a marketing/promotions term designating recordings which “broke” or “busted” onto the national “charts” of bestsellers, and it has since been extended to other commodities, mostly in entertainment: books, movies, games.

There was however a somewhat older parallel usage for sales: ‘chartbusting’  sales were those which increased so sharply that the line representing the value “busted through” the top of existing graph. My impression (and it is no more than that) is that this is closer to how *chartbuster* and *chartbusting* tend to be used outside the recording industry—for works which approach or break sales records. It’s not enough to make it onto the list of bestsellers—you have to be at or near the top of the list over a long period.

Some more general observations: *Any* word or phrase may be extended beyond its original scope to similar or analogous situations. Whether a particular novel use is “acceptable” depends only on its being *accepted*—used and understood—in discourse. Eventually the dictionaries will catch up.

So your best authority for contemporary usage is not a dictionary but a corpus of actual utterances. The most accessible such corpus for popular use is Google; sure enough, if you Google “chartbuster games” you will find<sup>†</sup> several such uses. Several of these are false hits on a game named “Chartbuster”, but there are others like this:

> Below we have short-listed some of the chartbuster games of this year. They simply excel with their breath-taking visual effects and classy gameplay. They are being highly talked about not only among gamers worldwide but also among game critics. —[blog.game4u.com, “The Game of the Year Contenders 2013”, posted 11/27/2013](http://blog.game4u.com/tag/buy-computer-games-online/)

A question which remains is whether the uses you find suggest suitability to the context and register in which you want to work. That is a judgment call.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or at least ***I*** found—Google reports different results in different places.